# Voice Recognition - IF hello OR hi is said

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, voice

Okay, so basically in C#, I want certain code to run when I say, for example, hello OR hi. I have gotten it so that when I say hello it runs the code but I can't figure out how to make it so that if I say hi instead it also runs the code. I don't want to make a whole if statement for both because I'm looking to make a whole lot in the future, (hello, hi, hey, how are you, etc).
This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;


namespace Voice_Recognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnDisable.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Hey", "Hi" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
            gBuilder.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognized);

        }
        void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string B = "\nBRIAN: ";
            string J = "\nYOU: ";
            string said = e.Result.Text;

            if (said == "Hello")
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += J + "Hello";
                string[] Hello = { "Hello.", "Hi.", "Hey.", "What's up?", "Howdy.", "Nice to see you.", "Hey, how are you going?", "Yo.", "Hiya", "Sup.", "Wassup?",
                        "What's crackin?", "How you goin'?", "What's new?", "How are you?",
                        "Hello Jake.", "Hi Jake.", "Hey Jake.", "What's up Jake?", "Howdy Jake.", "Nice to see you Jake", "Hey, how are you going Jake?", "Yo Jake.",
                        "Hiya Jake.", "Sup Jake?", "Wassup Jake?", "How you goin' Jake?", "What's new Jake?", "How are you Jake?"};
                richTextBox1.Text += B + Hello[new Random().Next(0, Hello.Length)];
            }            
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnDisable.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a list of your potential inputs and then see if that contains what was said

```
string[] validInputs = new string[]{"Hello", "Hi"};
if(validInputs.Contains(said))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I do that there is an error under 'Contains' which says 'string[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains''

Comment: @Jakegeyer27 - Apologies, you need to include `Linq` with `using System.Linq` [MSDN for contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: By the way, also now I can't get rid of
'Choices commands = new Choices();
commands.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Hey", "Hi" });'
in my Form1_Load even though I don't need them

Comment: @Jakegeyer27 - Well the commands is still being used as a parameter for some of the other constructors, you can replace the string parameter in that with the list of inputs that you just made with my answer if you wish (`commands.Add(validInputs)`).

Comment: it says that 'the name 'validInputs' does not exist in the current context' because I had to put it into the recEngine_SpeechRecognized

Comment: You will need to change its scope, make it an instance variable. (For example, `recEngine` is also an instance variable)

Comment: How would I do that? :P Sorry I'm really new to C#

Comment: Move it to where `recEngine` is, you can read more on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx), this is for vb.net but the functionality is the same